# ModalPopup is not working

Tags: asp.net, modalpopupextender

Since i changed my website from .NET 4.0 to 3.5 ModalPopup is not working.
The problem is there's no error message showing. So i can't figure out how to fix it.
Has anyone had the same problem before?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="btnpopup" runat="server" Text="Button" /> 

        <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpe" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnpopup" PopupControlID="pnlpopup" 
            CancelControlID="btnCancelpopup" EnableViewState="true" DropShadow="true" />

            <asp:Panel ID="pnlpopup" runat="server" Width="400px">
                test
            <asp:Button ID="btnCancelpopup" runat="server" Text="Button" />
        </asp:Panel>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, I think the fastest solution to your problem is to create a new solution based on .NET 3.5, and move your files over.

I built two solutions, one in 3.5 and one in 4.0, installed the ajaxcontroltoolkit via the Nuget package manager for vs2010 ([here](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/), which also includes instrucs. for vs2008) and both ran your code correctly.

When I rolled back the 4.0 solution to 3.5, the error I received was:

> "Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its
>   dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the
>   currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded."

The dependency appears to be with System.Web.Extensions as the following error indicates:

> Error 2   Assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.1.60501.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e' uses
>   'System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version than
>   referenced assembly 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

You may be able to fiddle around with the appropriate dependencies, but I personally wouldn't bother.